# Supabase and Next.js - How to make change password page accessible only to authenticated users

Tags: authentication, next.js, next.js13, supabase, supabase-js

I have a `next.js` application and I am following the documentation for allowing users to reset passwords.

So far, I built the password reset page and made it publicly accessible with a form asking for the user's email address. Upon submission of the form, I use the `supabase.auth.resetPasswordForEmail` API to request a password reset link for the user. I also provided the `redirectTo` parameter pointing to the change password page.

```
await supabase.auth.resetPasswordForEmail(email, {
      redirectTo: `${requestUrl.origin}/change-password`,
    }
```

Now in the documentation, it says to make the change password page accessible only to authenticated users. In my `next.js middleware` file I tried:

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const res = NextResponse.next();

const supabase = createMiddlewareClient({ req, res });

  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

if (!user && req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/update-password')) {
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/sign-in', req.url));
}

return res;
```

The idea is that only authenticated users will be allowed to the /update-password page and unauthenticated users will be redirected to the sign-in page. However, right now everytime I try to direct to `req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/update-password')` from the email link sent by supabase, the `supabase.auth.getUser()` and `supabase.auth.getSession()` are both null.

So if both of those are returning null, how else am I supposed to make the change password page accessible only to authenticated users?

Comment: If you are using @supabase/ssr package, you have to make sure the auth info is extracted from the cookies before calling getUser().  I hope step 4 of this guide helps. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/nextjs

Comment: If you are not using @supabase/ssr package, then remove your middleware. You should determine if the user has an active session or not on the client side rather than the server side.